# The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.2 instead of 10.10.2

Tags: xcode, macos

While developing an application in MAC. In which i display too many pop-ups notifying system internal information like CPU usage, sytem settings.For which i am using NSalert to show popups and get the display information from background thread. My app is working properly in 10.8.X version. But when it comes to yesomite it gets crashed with an empty popup and there after app hangs. When i digged deeper in console i found this  log. Is this relevant, if so please some one answer me with a way to make selector to return correct version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with CRD's answer, but for completeness, an alternative is to use `Gestalt` to get the 3 parts of the version separately, using `gestaltSystemVersionMajor`, `gestaltSystemVersionMinor`, and `gestaltSystemVersionBugFix`.

Comment: While *currently* this works the whole of `Gestalt` has been deprecated since 10.8. Therefore it is best to move away from using it now.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what system & compiler you are using, or what the log you found.

The documentation for `Gestalt` states that the minor version number sticks at 9 - it's a single BCD digit after all.

Compiling:

```
SInt32 number;
if (Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersion, &number) != noErr)
    number = 0;
NSLog(@"version = %8x", number);
```

on Yosemite with Xcode 6.1 produces the warning:

> gestaltSystemVersion' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.8 - Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property instead.

You can test for `operatingSystemVersion` using `respondsToSelector:` and use that in preference to `Gestalt` when it is available.

HTH